# Send data to angularjs app in realtime

Tags: angularjs, node.js, real-time

I have an AngularJS app that displays data. The app must display data in real-time and I don't want to make permanent request to my `api`. Is it possible to make connection between my server and my AngularJS app so that when new data arrives on the server, the server notifies AngularJS and sends it data to be displayed?

Thank you in advance.

Sorry if duplicate (i have not found answer to my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common use for the **WebSocket** so I'm pretty sure you should check [socket.io](http://socket.io/).
long pooling will be a good help for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that both https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html or  http://socket.io/ could do the trick.Depends on what you needs.